# Have I understood MySQL behavior correctly?

Tags: mysql, default

I created the table with such a command
`CREATE TABLE sometable (number INT DEFAULT (300));`

```
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| Field  | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra             |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
| number | int  | YES  |     | 300     | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
+--------+------+------+-----+---------+-------------------+
```

And because of expression (300) instead of simple 300 MySQL thinks it is an expression, he calculate it every time when you add default value to the table, so MySQL added a `DEFAULT_GENERATED`. Right?
(When I create the same table but without brackets around of 300, `DEFAULT_GENERATED` isn't added.)

Comment: seems like a low level bug, expression can be simplified to a constant value https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-columns-table.html "for columns that have an expression default value." yes but what is an expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have the correct understanding You can put an expression into the `DEFAULT` that is only a single literal value. That counts as an expression if you use the syntax cue of the parentheses.

If you're concerned about the performance overhead of the expression, I would expect that calculating such a simple expression (a single literal) is not likely to be a significant performance problem.

Keep in mind the `DEFAULT` expression is used only when you `INSERT` and furthermore only if you don't provide a value for that column.

In a later `SELECT` query, there is no difference. It reads the stored value, whether you originally inserted the row by using `DEFAULT` or by specifying a value.